# layoutmargin varies on all android devices

Tags: android-layout

My Layout margin is varying in every device. I have tested in Note 2 and Galaxy Grand. in both the device margin is varying, I have read all the details provided in android supported screen. I have three layout folder i.e `layout`,`layout-medium`,`layout-small`. When i run my project in both the device both are taking layout from layout folder.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

>

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lowerlayout"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#80000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/feedback" />

     <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="FEEDBACK"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/my_booking" />

     <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="MY BOOKING"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/like_us"/>

      <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="RATE US"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/upperlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lowerlayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
    android:background="#80000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/search" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SEARCH"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
       >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginToApp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/login"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="LOGIN"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/map"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="MAPS"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="@drawable/gallery"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="GALLERY"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/setting"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SETTINGS"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/logo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using dimes.xml located in values folder and create a different values folder for each screen density values-hdpi, values-xhdpi,values-xxhdpi etc etc.